# Using regular expression to return a tuple or list from fasta format

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file that looks like the following:

```
>gene_name_1
FYCVLAHWG
GGGGGGGGG
>gene_name_2
FYCVLAHWG
>gene_name_3
FYCVLAHWG
>gene_name_4
FYCVLAHG
>gene_name_5
FCVLAHWG
>gene_name_6
YCVLAHWG
```

and I did the following:

```
from sys import argv
import re

script, input_file = argv

opened_file = open(input_file).read()

test = re.findall('>.*\n|\n.*\n>', opened_file)

print test
```

And I get the following:

```
['>gene_name_1\n', '\nGGGGGGGGG\n>', '\nFYCVLAHWG\n>', '\nFYCVLAHWG\n>', '\nFYCVLAHG\n>', '\nFCVLAHWG\n>']
```

But I was hoping to get the following:

```
['>gene_name_1\n', '\nGGGGGGGGG\nFYCVLAHWG\n>', '>gene_name_2\n', '\nFYCVLAHWG\n>', '>gene_name_3\n', '\nFYCVLAHG\n>', '>gene_name_4\n', '\nFCVLAHWG\n>', '>gene_name_5\n', '\nFYCVLAHWG\n>', '>gene_name_6\n', '\nYCVLAHWG\n>]
```

Why are the rest of the stuff missing??

Comment: Post the file contents.

Comment: Just updated. Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that what you want can be accomplished by a simple `test = open(input_file).read().split('\n')` but it is possible that I'm missing some fine points of your question.

Comment: @user3121361 just post the file contents in your question. I'll edit that. And note that once a character is included in one match and the same won't be matched by the second pattern.

Comment: If I just use \n to split then the "FYCVLAHWG GGGGGGGGG" would be in two different string and I want them to be in one string instead.

Comment: Yes, now I see.  May I say that it was hard to distinguish in your OP?

Comment: What's OP? I'm sorry to ask that kind of stupid question LOL, this is my second week into programming LOL.

Comment: OP stands for Original Post

Comment: Oh I see LOL. ya.. I apologize for my OP and I will learn how to post it better next time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = r""">gene_name_1
FYCVLAHWG
GGGGGGGGG
>gene_name_2
FYCVLAHWG
>gene_name_3
FYCVLAHWG
>gene_name_4
FYCVLAHG
>gene_name_5
FCVLAHWG
>gene_name_6
YCVLAHWG"""

import re

x = re.findall(">.*?\n|(?:[^>].*?\n)+", s)
print(x)
```

produces:

```
['>gene_name_1\n', 'FYCVLAHWG\nGGGGGGGGG\n', '>gene_name_2\n', 'FYCVLAHWG\n', '>gene_name_3\n', 'FYCVLAHWG\n', '>gene_name_4\n', 'FYCVLAHG\n', '>gene_name_5\n', 'FCVLAHWG\n', '>gene_name_6\n']
```

which is almost what you requested.
**EDIT**:
I just realized: this misses the last line :( [because there is no newline at the end of the last line]
**EDIT2**:
Some more details on the regular expression:

- `[^>]` matches any character that is not a >
- `re.findall(regexpr,input)` if no capturing groups are defined in regexpr it returns all substings that match the pattern, otherwise it returns only the matched groups. Thats why I used:
- `(?:)` is a non-capturing group, i.e. its content will not be added to the groups list of the match.

---

But I have to say: Do you really want the ">" and newline characters in your output? As has been commented before, you might be better of reading the file line by line (or splitting at \n).

An other approach would be:

```
result = []
cache= []
with open(input_file) as f:
  for line in f:
    if line[0] == '>':
      result.append('\n'.join(cache))
      result.append(line)
      cache = []
    else:
      cache.append(line)
  result.append('\n'.join(cache))

print result
```

---

or:

```
import collections

key = '<unknown>' # required in case the first line is not '>...'
result = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open(input_file) as f:
  for line in f:
    if line[0] == '>':
      key = line[1:]
    else:
      result[key].append(line)

print result
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'gene_name_1': ['FYCVLAHWG', 'GGGGGGGGG'], 'gene_name_4': ['FYCVLAHG'], 'gene_name_3': ['FYCVLAHWG'], 'gene_name_2': ['FYCVLAHWG'], 'gene_name_6': ['YCVLAHWG'], 'gene_name_5': ['FCVLAHWG']})
```

Comment: There is no newline at the end of the string because you haven't put a newline at the end of your test string... Usually files are newline terminated, so the OP (@user3121361 OP stands, now, for Original Poster...) may use (and accept) your fine answer as is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
import re

pattern = r'(^>[^\n]*)([^>]*)'
flags = re.M|re.S
test_string = '''
>gene_name_1
FYCVLAHWG
GGGGGGGGG
>gene_name_2
FYCVLAHWG
>gene_name_3
FYCVLAHWG
>gene_name_4
FYCVLAHG
>gene_name_5
FCVLAHWG
>gene_name_6
YCVLAHWG
'''
print(list(re.findall(pattern, test_string, flags=flags)))
# [('>gene_name_1', '\nFYCVLAHWG\nGGGGGGGGG\n'), ('>gene_name_2', '\nFYCVLAHWG\n'), ('>gene_name_3', '\nFYCVLAHWG\n'), ('>gene_name_4', '\nFYCVLAHG\n'), ('>gene_name_5', '\nFCVLAHWG\n'), ('>gene_name_6', '\nYCVLAHWG\n')]
```